# Unordered list in the prawn view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I have a Rails application where the user can insert text with a WYSIWYG-Editor.
The customer wants now to be able to insert lists.
But the output of the Text appears with no list just escaped html-list-tags.

Gems:
gem 'prawn_rails'
gem 'prawn'

Does anyone has an idea?

THX

Comment: only in the pdf or do you have same phenomenon in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by my own. I just replacted the tags with new line and bullet points.